# Convert the Infopath Form into PDF or Excel in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: infopath, excel-services, pdf

We have designed an Infopath Form and published as a document template on a library. Now, we would like to add a feature to export the InfoPath Form details to Excel or publish the InfoPath Form as PDF from SharePoint 2010.

Please suggest.

Note:
As the InfoPath Form has too may field, we may not be able to promote all the fields.

Comment: do we have any freeware? like codeplex solutions.

Comment: What kind of InfoPath forms you have developed, is it InfoPath filler forms or web browsable InfoPath forms.?

Answer (score 2):

there is 3rd party tool called Muhimbi PDF Converter
http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-infopath-to-ms-word-excel-xps.html

Comment: This is indeed a supported scenario (Including the conversion of attachments). Drop support@muhimbi.com a line if you have any questions about this, we love to help.